# Auto width of images inside div display:table so they are of the same height

Tags: html, css

I want to display images inside divs which have `display:table-cell` style, in parent `display:table` div. The pictures are of various height, but all more than 400px. I set the `max-height: 200px` on them. It works very well in Chrome, which automatically calculates width for each cell so that the images are roughly of the same height (±2px). However, it does not work in IE, in which the table stretches outside the parent div, despite `max-width` and/or `width` set to 100%. To fix it, `table-layout:fixed` can be used, but then images are not of the same height. Does anyone know how to make it working? Thanks.

JsFiddle:  [jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/4](http://jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/4)

The problem is than in IE, the table and table row will exceed the container's width, even when using table, tr and td tags : [jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/7](http://jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/7). The table-layout fixes it, but makes images of different height. I want images to be the same height, and also make the table not overflow the parent div. Wish IE was smarter.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please show some code, html and more css, possible put into jsfiddle.net too.

Comment: @Jay, indeed, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/4/ Currently, the parent div will overflow the container in IE but not in Chrome, but if table-layout:fixed added to parent, it won't overflow, but images will be of different height.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. I have checked and it seems to be the same in each browser for me. What version of IE are you checking in, Im using 11

Comment: Ignore my last comment. It seems that img needs to be width: 100%; not max-width: 100%; see below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Alrite, cool! Thanks man! One special case is when the image width is less than 100%, but I think I can deal with that.

Comment: Your welcome. Why would one image be less than 100%? i may be able to help there if its required, just wondering why?

Comment: It could be when I have 5 images, 4 horizontal with width 200 and one vertical with width 50, or something like that. I really need to test this scenario, but not sure if it's worth worrying about, since I purposefully load large images (e.g. 400px max side when the container is 1000px max).

Comment: Once you have tested and it causes issues please dont hesitate to let me know, ill try and help if possible.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I think it might not even be possible since browsers render table-cells according to the content, so the parent div of an image will have some width that is not going to exceed the image's width ... not sure.

Comment: hi! sorry, it does not work when images are of different height:http://jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/8/. I guess adding height: 100% should fix it as well but then the images are not of the natural proportions.

Comment: What browser are you checking on? height auto works on firefox, height 100% works on both.

Comment: height 100% will stretch the image. i'm checking in Chrome

Comment: Its hard for me to see any stretch images when you are using block coloured images, can you send a link so i may be able to help.

Comment: hi! i've updated the images: http://jsfiddle.net/6qdjdrLe/9/ it's not super clear, but you get the point. thx!

Comment: I think what your asking for is pretty impossible with css. Your going to need to either photoshop the images before hand into the suitable ratio so that they do not stretch, or your going to have to add some javascript/ php that will crop the images into the correct ratio when uploaded to stop stretching. Sorry mate

Comment: it's alrite, I had a feeling it was kind of impossible. shame it works in chrome and safari but not ie. I think with js, it can be done: http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?lang=en&language=en&ref_site=photo&search_source=search_form&version=llv1&anyorall=all&safesearch=1&search_tracking_id=Sb1GeSaYBG5C7nVxhYZtYw&searchterm=southampton&show_color_wheel=1&orient=&commercial_ok=&media_type=images&search_cat=&searchtermx=&photographer_name=&people_gender=&people_age=&people_ethnicity=&people_number=&color= anyway, thanks for your help!